# Django query: field is substring

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Django I have my Site model that contains the field "base_url" that's the base url of the site. I've an object like this:

```
foo = Site(base_url="http://foo_base_url.com/")
foo.save()
```

I receive an url and I want to obtain the site object having this url. I would like to perform a query in django like this:

```
Site.objects.get(base_url__is_substring="http://foo_base_url.com/something_non_base_url")
```

How can I perform this query?
Thanx

edit:
It doesn't exist a pattern for base_url, my foo site can be:

```
foo = Site(base_url="http://foo.com/base/url/")
```

Comment: Are you looking for "base_url__contains" or "base_url__icontains"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not provided by the Django ORM but you can use the `where` param described under the [reference for QuerySet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/):

```
url = "http://foo_base_url.com/something_non_base_url"
Site.objects.extra(where=["%s LIKE CONCAT('%%',field,'%%')"], params=[url]).get()
```

Keep in mind that *there is no standard method of concatenation across DMBS* so if you migrate, you'll have to migrate this code.

The only portable method would be to filter it using Python:

```
sites = [site for site in Site.objects.all() if site.base_url in url]
```

although this is of course not ideal for huge data sets.

Comment: I was going to change the design but I was curious to know if a solution exists.

Comment: Since extra is being deprecated, is there a way to write the query without extra, or Raw. How about using F objects? and annotations?